# error: generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, algorithm, generics

I have function which make flatted array from nested array. It works perfectly for int array.

```
let array: [Any] = [1, 2, [3]]

func makeFlatArray(_ array: [Any]) -> [Int] {
    var flatArray = [Int]()
    for item in array {
        if let item = item as? Int {
            flatArray.append(item)
        } else if let item = item as? [Any] {
            let result = makeFlatArray(item)
            flatArray += result
        }
    }
    return flatArray
}
```

But I want make it generic and I have got error when trying.

```
func makeFlatArrayGeneric<T>(_ array: [Any]) -> [T] {
    var flatArray = [T]()
    for item in array {
        if let item = item as? T {
            flatArray.append(item)
        } else if let item = item as? [Any] {
            let result = makeFlatArrayGeneric(item)
            flatArray += result
        }
    }
    return flatArray
}
```

Error:

```
Playground execution failed:

error: FlatNestedArraysExample.playground:22:26: error: generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
            let result = makeFlatArrayGeneric(item)
                         ^

FlatNestedArraysExample.playground:16:6: note: in call to function 'makeFlatArrayGeneric'
func makeFlatArrayGeneric<T>(_ array: [Any]) -> [T] {
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler the type of T.

```
func makeFlatArrayGeneric<T>(_ array: [Any]) -> [T] {
    var flatArray = [T]()
    for item in array {
        if let item = item as? T {
            flatArray.append(item)
        } else if let item = item as? [Any] {
            let result: [T] = makeFlatArrayGeneric(item)
            flatArray += result
        }
    }
    return flatArray
}

let array: [Any] = [1, 2, [3], [4, [5]]]
let items: [Int] = makeFlatArrayGeneric(array) //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

A more functional approach to solving your problem.

```
extension Array {
    func flatten() -> Array<Element> {
        return self.flatMap({ element -> [Element] in
            if let array = element as? Array {
                return array.flatten()
            } else {
                return [element]
            }
        })
    }
}

let items: [Int] = array.flatten() //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 4):

You gotta do something to make swift aware what is `T`, one way to do this is to assign the return value to a variable whose type is known:

```
let result: [T] = makeFlatArrayGeneric(item)
```

Another way is to pass the type as a parameter:

```
func makeFlatArrayGeneric<T>(_ array: [Any], type: T.Type) -> [T] {
    var flatArray = [T]()
    for item in array {
        if let item = item as? T {
            flatArray.append(item)
        } else if let item = item as? [Any] {
            let result = makeFlatArrayGeneric(item, type: type)
            flatArray += result
        }
    }
    return flatArray
}
```

And call it like this:

```
makeFlatArrayGeneric(yourArray, type: Int.self)
```